# Is it correct to say "consecutively in time"?

Tags: programming

I'm writing a technical report and I want to emphasize that each sample that I have stored in a buffer has been collected before the following one. Can I say,

> The samples from the buffer are known to have been captured consecutively in time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds redundant to me.  I'd put a period after "consecutively".  Alternatively, you might try "in chronological order".

Comment: 'In chronological order' does not mean the same as consecutively. A series of events can occur in chronological order, without being consecutive.

Comment: @Dan: If a series of events are consecutive then they are also chronological, no? So, consecutive would be a more restrictive term than chronological?

Comment: "Consecutively" implies some higher density; an ordering without gaps. The numbers [1, 2, 5] are not consecutive, but are in order. If I read that a list of samples were consecutive, I would assume that the list presented is all samples at some maximum sampling precision. (Either way, it is grammatical.)

Comment: @MrHen: Yes; I just wanted to make the point that 'consecutively' and 'in chronological order' are not equivalent, in case Jal is not a native speaker.

Answer (score 7):

I cannot definitively say that *consecutively in time* is incorrect, but the phrasing is awkward, at best. I would suggest the good old simple expression, *one after other*. More formally, you could also say, *in succession*:

> - The samples from the buffer are known to have been captured one after the other.
> - The samples from the buffer are known to have been captured in succession.

Answer (score 6):

I think `consecutively` should suffice; it's as if the 'in time' is an inelegant hint as to what consecutively actually means, to those who aren't sure.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could easily use the word, "sequentially."

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sequential)

> se·quen·tial   
> [si-kwen-shuhl]
>
> –adjective
>
> 1.
> characterized by regular sequence  of parts.
>
> 2.
> following; subsequent; consequent.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it could be used to make a distinction if the word were also serving other meanings:

> **con·sec·u·tive**  (kn-sky-tv) *adj.*
>
> 1. Following one after another without interruption; successive: was absent on three consecutive days; won five consecutive games on the road.
> 2. Marked by logical sequence.
> 3. Grammar Expressing consequence or result: a consecutive clause.

From [theFreeOnlineDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consecutive)

If you had just used the word in its logical or grammatical sense, you might add "in time" if you then wanted to be clear about which version a chronological statement was serving.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are able to break a fundamental law of physics, consecutively *in time* is redundant.

If this is a technical report and you're discussing buffers, then your audience should/will probably understand FIFO.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO

A queue is FIFO, a stack is LIFO.

Answer (score 1):

Just one word: `successively`.